# Is it common to pause in the center of a word? why do people do that?

Tags: pronunciation

It sounds the man [saying](https://youtu.be/LdDLEikgbWM?t=16)

> what you're about to see is the story of a young man whose name is Ben
>   Underwood. when he was born at an early age he had `cancer` in both eyes
>   and they had to be surgically removed.

where he has a obvious pause between `can` and `cer`, I occasionally heard some other guys talk that way.

Is it common to pause in the center of a word? why do people do that?

Comment: It's quite normal, the speaker is enunciating the two syllables. Words that have two or more syllables, such as "com•pu•ter" can have infinitesimal breaks/interruptions between them.

Comment: It's probably a form of glottal stop.

Comment: @marcellothearcane So, it is reasonable to view that as a personal style, right?

Comment: @Mari-LouA In this particular case, the speaker pronounce that way to emphasize "cancer"?

Comment: When I mentioned "breaks" I meant that the pause between each syllable can be infinitesimal. I might emphasise the term can•cer as the speaker did. I don't find his pronunciation style unique.

Comment: Simply slowing down to the point of clearly enunciating each syllable can give the impression of a break in the rhythm which stresses an important or taboo word, like _cancer_.

Comment: I agree with @JohnLawler. There's no pause, but he makes the vowel of *can* a bit longer than expected.  (Hi John)

Comment: @JohnLawler  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.